# Theorem on Spectrum, point spectrum and the Calkin algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Apparently it's a theorem by Weyl.

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional, separable Hilbert space and let $A,B \in B(H)$.

Let $K(H)$ be the set of compact operators acting on $H$.

Show that if $A-B \in K(H)$ and if $\lambda \in \sigma(A)-\sigma_p(A)$, or if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of infinite multiplicity, then $\lambda \in \sigma(B)$.

Here $\sigma_p$ is the point spectrum, and it consists of the eigenvalues.

Hint: assume wlog $\lambda=0$(I'm not sure why we can do that) and write $A=B+(A-B)$.

Some thoughts:

We have two cases:

1. Suppose  $A-B \in K(H)$ and $\lambda \in \sigma(A)-\sigma_p(A)$.

Then we have $\lambda \in \sigma(B+(A-B))-\sigma_p(B+(A-B))$.

So $\lambda \in \sigma(B+ K(H))$ and $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $(B+ K(H))$.

Now I feel like I have to use the compactness of $A-B$. Not sure to continue.

2. Suppose  $A-B \in K(H)$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of infinite multiplicity. Then we have $\lambda \in \sigma_p(A-B)$.

Again.. I'm missing something about compactness.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For your first question: consider $A':=A-\lambda I$ and $B':=B-\lambda I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operator $T\in B(H)$ is said to be a *Fredholm operator* if the null space of $T$ is finite dimensional and the range of
$T$ has finite co-dimension.  In this case the *index* of $T$ is defined by
$$
  \text{ind}(T) = \text{dim}(\text{Ker}(T)) - \text{codim}(\text{Ran}(T)).
  $$

Among  the standard results of the theory of Fredholm opertors one has:

**Theorem**.  If $T$ is Fredholm and $K$ is compact,  then $T+K$ is also Fredholm and
$\text{ind}(T) = \text{ind}(T+K)$.

Letting $A'=A-\lambda $,  and $B'=B-\lambda $,  as suggested by @Berci,   we need to prove that,  if $A'-B'$ is compact,  and $A'$
fails to be invertible either because:

1. its null space is infinite dimensional,  or
2. $A'$ is injective,  but not surjective,

then $B'$ is also not invertible.

In order to prove this,  suppose by contradiction that $B'$ is invertible.  Then $B'$ is clearly Fredholm,  with
$\text{ind}(B') = 0$,
and
hence $A'$ is also Fredholm with $\text{ind}(A') = 0$.  However this is incompatible with either (1) or (2), so we have
arrived at a contradiction, proving that $B'$ is not invertible, and hence that $\lambda \in \sigma (B)$.

Comment: Thank you for the post! May I ask why $A', B'$ are Fredholm with index $0 $? I don't really see why their null spaces and ranges are finite dimensional.

Comment: Do you see why every invertible operator is Fredholm?

Comment: I learned this theorem that $T$ is invertible if and only if $\pi(T)$ is invertible in the Calkin algebra $(\pi:B(H) \rightarrow B(H)/K(H))$. Is it from that?

Comment: You should check on this statement because it is not correct.  Regarding my question, what is the null space and range of an invertible operator?

Comment: If $T\in B(H)$ is invertible, then $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(T))=0$ !!!  Except for this mistake, that is why $T$ is Fredholm.

Comment: I think you are reading things that are too advanced for your current level.  Maybe you should check with your instructor/advisor to give you something else to read.

Comment: Sorry, just one last question. Why do we have a contradiction to (2)?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That is because, under (2), $A'$ cannot have index 0.